# Tube Patch or tubeless plug

Tags: mountain-bike

For a quick on the trail temporary fix can I use a tubeless tire plug on my tube tire? Just to get me back to my car? I'm an 84 year old new biker (electric) so forgive me if this is dumb question.

Comment: I give you joy for beginning to ride a bike. Isn't it absolutely lovely?

Also welcome to [SE]. Have a look at self adhering patches, or much better good old patches. Also look into puncture resistant tyres, like Marathon Plus or Conti Tour, and some others.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but may resolve your problem. Bring a spare tube! Then you can fix/plug all you want when you get back home. That's what I do...

Answer (score 10):

A tubeles plug will not hold in a bicycles inner tube.

A tubeless plug is a short string of butyl rubber. About 1 cm in length and 2 mm wide. To fix a punctured tubeless tyre it is pushed with an awl into the hole. Together with sealant in the tyre it is good to seal cuts of up to 5 mm.

The inner tube's walls are too thin and too stretchy to seal it that way. The reasons are similar to those in my answer on sealants in inner tubes: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/64642/30402

Fixing a clincher tyre that contains an inner tube with such a patch will not seal the puncture. Air would still escape through the valve hole, gaps in the rim, along the tyre bead, and countless other spots.

Fixing a small hole in clincher tyre when an inner tube still holds air is not necessary. The tyre itself doesn't need to be air tight. It just needs to hold the tube inside and provide a good contact patch to the ground. The plug cannot fix large holes in a tyre (check tyre boots). In such a case the threads of the carcass are ripped and the tyre loses the strength it requires to resist the pressure of the filled inner tube.

Comment: In my experience a tubeles plug doesn't even hold in a fast tyre that is worn a bit (2000 km). That is, the thread was thin. The rubber of the thread and at the carcass wasn't providing enough surface on the inner side walls of the puncture to hold the plug. My old plugs fell out (they are supposed to fuse to the tyre.) and new plugs did not stay.

Answer (score 1):

I have no direct experience. However, I am going to guess no. Here's my rationale.

Tubeless plugs are basically coated ropes threaded onto a needle. You push the needle into the hole, then withdraw it. The tubeless plug sticks into the hole in the tire. I'd expect the sealant to be necessary to fill the gaps around the plug.

If you have a tubed setup, you need to plug the hole in the tube, not the tire. You'd have to make sure the tubeless plug went into the original hole in your tube. One issue is that you can't see the hole in the tube, you can only see the one in the tire. You would need to make sure that plug went into the hole in the tube. And actually, I'm not sure your plug is going to reliably make its way into the tube at all.

The other issue is that I believe you will need to have sealant in the tube for the reason I outlined above. I'm not sure tubeless sealant works as well in inner tubes as it does in tubeless tires. I haven't researched this issue thoroughly.

Also note: tubeless plugs are meant to deal with medium sized holes that are too large for tubeless sealant to seal unassisted. I suspect that the majority of punctures are smaller than what you'd need a plug for.

For tubed setups, my impression is that most riders would rely on putting in a spare tube, rather than patching the tube as your title mentions. Tube patches would come into play if we needed to repair multiple flats.

I think that multiple punctures are a relatively rare situation. I have done century rides where I just had one tube - admittedly, fellow cyclists would have lent me one if I'd had multiple flats. If you are in an event lasting longer than this and you have a tubed setup, I would guess thaat most cyclists would carry multiple spare tubes. Just for fun, Fiona Kolbinger won the Transcontinental Race (the entire race, not just the women's race) with a time of a bit over 10 days. This post by [Apidura](https://www.apidura.com/journal/fiona-kolbingers-transcontinental-race-winning-kit/) suggests that she carried 4 spare tubes, a spare tire, patches, and a tire boot (among many other spares and food). As I mentioned, I suspect that she would have changed tubes during the race, rather than patching them. This would save time. I would guess she patched tubes at rest stops. The author of [this post](https://www.360velo.com/dirty-kanza-200-the-ultimate-guide/) on Dirty Kanza, a 206-mile gravel race, carried 3 spare tubes, a patch kit, and a tire boot, in addition to having his tires set up tubeless.

Comment: I believe it is possible to use tubeless sealant in a tube, at least I have read of people doing it.  But it has to be in there already before you get the puncture for it to be useful.

Comment: Oh, and I've had 3 punctures _simultaneously_.  (Someone apparently thought it would be fun to scatter brass tacks across a trail lightly covered in pine needles.)  It may not be common, but if you ride enough you _will_ have more than one puncture on a ride.

Comment: @DavidW if your putting in a plug into a tube, you could inject the sealant at that time (or after through the valve core)

Comment: @PaulH I would be concerned that trying to inject the sealant at that time it wouldn't be properly distributed to effectively seal the hole.

Comment: @DavidW it's fine. the sealant needs to be distributed. when i notice a "gusher" out on the trail, I stop, dismount (to get my weight of the tire) and give it a good spin.

Comment: @PaulH admit it: you do that only for they joy of squirting sticky goo all over your bike, trail, jersey, and club. ;-)

Comment: luckily it's very rarelymore than `PSSSSST PSST psst pt` and then my magic concoction (1:1 orange seal and stan's) has done its work!